# wordpress not redirecting from php file

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a form in wordpress where the form action = swagHome.php.  In that file I try to redirect with:

header("Location: https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/");

but it's not working.  I definitely get to that line of code but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

if it's redirecting to a url within the same site you can use [wp_safe_redirect()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/), otherwise there's wp_redirect()

```
wp_safe_redirect( $url );
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the following from cs50:

```
function redirect($destination){    

// handle URL
if (preg_match("/^https?:\/\//", $destination)){
   header("Location: " . $destination);
}else if (preg_match("/^\//", $destination)){
   // handle absolute path
   $protocol = (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"])) ? "https" : "http";
   $host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
   header("Location: $protocol://$host$destination");
}else if (preg_match("/^www/",$destination)){
    //handle www addresses (added by rss)
    $protocol = (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"])) ? "https" : "http";
    header("Location: $protocol://$destination");
}else{
   // handle relative path  
   // adapted from http://www.php.net/header
   $protocol = (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"])) ? "https" : "http";
   $host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
   $path = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]), "/\\");
   header("Location: $protocol://$host$path/$destination");      
}


// exit immediately since we're redirecting anyway
/****************
  print($_SERVER["HTTPS"].'<br>');
  print($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'<br>');
  print($host.'<br>');
  print($path.'<br>');
  print($destination.'<br>');
  print_r2($_SERVER);
*****************/
  exit;
}
```